# Selecting a specific response from a HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpresponse

For reference, say the response from my GET request is this:

```json
{"United States", "332,915,073", "20.93 Trillion"}
```

Country, Population and their GDP.

If I wanted the population value from this response, how would I put that value into a variable or print out that value.

Answer (score 1):

first there is one problem the [Json](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) Response is not valid. 
Actually, it can be an array like `["United States", "332,915,073", "20.93 Trillion"]`, but this format is not valid.

> you can use [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) tool to check your json format.

but if it is an array you can use this code:

```
var values = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string []>(json);
Console.WriteLine(values[1]);
```

you can run it online [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fpyCYV).